# E2017 Pointer type required using move function in Delphi 7 way

Tags: delphi, pointers, delphi-xe4

I'm trying to port a project from Delphi 7 to the new Delphi XE4 and I'm facing a problem with the **move** function :

```
{Create a temp record buffer}
HoldRec := AllocMem(RecordSize);
{Fill the temp record buffer with the current record}
move(ActiveBuffer^, HoldRec^, RecordSize); //Here the E2017 Error
```

The compiler throw an : `[dcc32 Error] E2017 Pointer type required` , error when arrive at the **move** statement ...

Why ? In Delphi 7 it compile without any problem, why Delphi XE4 doesn't compile ?

The declaration section is as follows :

```
FBuffers: TBufList;
HoldRec : PChar;
FActiveRecord :integer;


function TDataSet.ActiveBuffer: TRecBuf;
begin
  Result := FBuffers[FActiveRecord];
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Delphi 7, TRecBuf was a pointer of some type, I'm not sure exactly what. In XE4, it is declared as NativeInt. You'd need to cast it to be a pointer to make your code compile.

```
move(Pointer(ActiveBuffer)^, HoldRec^, RecordSize);
```

I would also point out that HoldRec is now PWideChar in Unicode XE4, but it was PAnsiChar in Delphi 7. I suspect you'll need to deal with that one way or another. Quite possibly you'd need to change the declaration to PAnsiChar, but I cannot say for sure from here.

Comment: I also faced the same problem and tried to solve with your solution. My line is    "Move(MemBlock.Block^,List.List^,Size*SizeOf(Pointer));".  It does not look like the way it can be worked. How should it look like?

Comment: @user Please don't ask questions in comments. We might guess that `List` is `TList` since its `List` property changed type. Look at the source code for `TList`. Work it out. It won't be hard.