# E2017 Pointer type required for List

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

From Delphi 2007 under Win XP to Xe7 under Win7,

I am not sure why this highlighted line won't work

```
Error : [dcc32 Error] utilmemblock.pas(935): E2017 Pointer type required

//D:Convert a memory block to a List. Odd sizes are truncated.
procedure MemBlockToList(const MemBlock:TMemBlock;List:TList);
var
  Size:Integer;
begin
  Size:=(MemBlock.Size div SizeOf(Pointer));
  List.Count:=Size;
  Move(MemBlock.Block^,List.Last^,Size*SizeOf(Pointer)); // This error points to this line
end;
```

I have checked this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770751/e2017-pointer-type-required-using-move-function-in-delphi-7-way) but I could not work out how to apply it to my problem.

Comment: Plesae try this `Move(Pointer(MemBlock.Block)^, List.Last^,Size*SizeOf(Pointer)); `

Comment: @user You've asked 79 questions but only voted 4 times. Might I respectfully suggest that you consider engaging more fully with our community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Statement of assumptions**

- I'm assuming that `MemBlock` is a type that you are in control of, and so is not the source for the error.
- I'm assuming that `List.Last` actually reads `List.List`.

**Answer, based upon those assumptions**

In older Delphi versions `TList.List` was a pointer to a static array. In modern Delphi `TList.List` has been changed to be a dynamic array of type `TPointerList` where

```
TPointerList = array of Pointer;
```

So your code should read

```
Move(MemBlock.Block^, Pointer(List.List)^, Size*SizeOf(Pointer));
```

Comment: One Solution to the E2017 Pointer type required when converting an older project to DXE5 involved just leaving off the dereferencing operator ^ as advised by the online documentation.